# Powershell break a long array into a array of array with length of N in one line?

Tags: powershell

For example, given a list `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8` and a number 4, it returns a list of list with length of 4, that is
`(1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8), (1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8)`.

Basically I want to implement the following Python code in Powershell.

```py
s = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
z = zip(*[iter(s)]*4)  # Here N is 4
# z is (1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8), (1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8)
```

The following script returns 17 instead of 5.

```
$a = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0
$b = 0..($a.Length / 4) | % {  @($a[($_*4)..($_*4 + 4 - 1)]) } 
$b.Length
```

Comment: Nice solution. How would you handle a number of elements not divisible by N? Which is 4 in this case.  $a = 1..18

Comment: @DougFinke Creating an variable `$n = 4`, and replace all the 4s with `$n` should work.

Comment: Agreed. I guess what I'm asking is. What do you do with the left overs when you have a array of #'s that is not divisible by N?

Comment: @DougFinke I used `0..($a.Length / 4)` instead of `1..($a.Length /4)`. So basically it added one more group. There will be an empty array if the length is divided by 4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
PS> $a = 1..16
PS> $z=for($i=0; $i -lt $a.length; $i+=4){ ,($a[$i]..$a[$i+3])}
PS> $z.count
4    

PS> $z[0]
1
2
3
4

PS> $z[1]
5
6
7
8

PS> $z[2]
9
10
11
12

PS> $z[3]
13
14
15
16
```

Comment: The accepted solution only works for consecutive integers.

For instance when $i is 0, $a[$i] is 1 and $a[$i+3] is 4. Hence 1 .. 4 will work. But the correct solution is

     `$z=for($i=0; $i -lt $a.length; $i+=4){ ,($a[$i .. ($i+3)])}`

Comment: @PeterReavy great answer!

Answer (score 56):

This is a bit old, but I figured I'd throw in the method I use for splitting an array into chunks.  You can use Group-Object with a constructed property:

```
$bigList = 1..1000

$counter = [pscustomobject] @{ Value = 0 }
$groupSize = 100

$groups = $bigList | Group-Object -Property { [math]::Floor($counter.Value++ / $groupSize) }
```

`$groups` will be a collection of GroupInfo objects; in this case, each group will have exactly 100 elements (accessible as `$groups[0].Group`, `$groups[1].Group`, and so on.)  I use an object property for the counter to avoid scoping issues inside the -Property script block, since a simple `$i++` doesn't write back to the original variable.  Alternatively, you can use `$script:counter = 0` and `$script:counter++` and get the same effect without a custom object.

Comment: I would like to use this but I need to group by an additional property first. How can I have `$counter` reset each time the `basedomain` property changes?

Comment: I think this is the most elegant answer as it uses the pipeline.

Comment: Thank you @DaveWyatt, I used this sort of logic for an array of strings with a bit of adjusted to this logic you shared: `$div = [Math]::Round(($List.Count / 4),0);
$counter = [pscustomobject] @{ Value = 0 };
$groups = $List | Group-Object -Property { [math]::Floor($counter.Value++ / $div) };
($groups | ? {$_.Name -eq 0}).Group;
($groups | ? {$_.Name -eq 1}).Group;
($groups | ? {$_.Name -eq 2}).Group;
($groups | ? {$_.Name -eq 3}).Group;`

Comment: This is old, but here from 2022 I was able to divide a group of 43K computer names in 8 seconds. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 12):

Wrote this in 2009 [PowerShell Split-Every Function](http://www.dougfinke.com/blog/index.php/2009/10/14/powershell-split-every-function/)

Probably can be improved.

```
Function Split-Every($list, $count=4) {
    $aggregateList = @()

    $blocks = [Math]::Floor($list.Count / $count)
    $leftOver = $list.Count % $count
    for($i=0; $i -lt $blocks; $i++) {
        $end = $count * ($i + 1) - 1

        $aggregateList += @(,$list[$start..$end])
        $start = $end + 1
    }    
    if($leftOver -gt 0) {
        $aggregateList += @(,$list[$start..($end+$leftOver)])
    }

    $aggregateList    
}

$s = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

$r = Split-Every $s 4

$r[0]
""
$r[1]
""
$r[2]
""
$r[3]
```

Comment: If the length of the list is < $count then $start and $end are used in the $aggregateList code uninitialized (or set to unknown values).

Fix is to add $start=$end=0 above the for loop.

Comment: I had an issue with this one, it was ripping apart strings when I had one item in my $list, so I my fix was to add if ($list.Count -eq 1) { return @($list) } above the $aggregateList declaration.

Answer (score 5):

Providing a solution using `select`. It doesn't need to worry whether `$list.Count` can be divided by `$chunkSize`.

```
function DivideList {
    param(
        [object[]]$list,
        [int]$chunkSize
    )

    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $list.Count; $i += $chunkSize) {
        , ($list | select -Skip $i -First $chunkSize)
    }
}

DivideList -list @(1..17) -chunkSize 4 | foreach { $_ -join ',' }
```

Output:

```
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
9,10,11,12
13,14,15,16
17
```

Comment: The advantage of this solution is that it is applicable on an array of strings as well.

Answer (score 3):

@Shay Levy Answer: if you change the value of a to 1..15 then your solution not working anymore ( Peter Reavy comment )

So this worked for me:

```
$a = 1..15
$z=for($i=0; $i -lt $a.length; $i+=4){if ($a.length -gt ($i+3)) { ,($a[$i]..$a[$i+3])} else { ,($a[$i]..$a[-1])}}
$z.count
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0
$b = 0..([Math]::ceiling($a.Length / 4) - 1) | 
    % {  @(, $a[($_*4)..($_*4 + 4 - 1)]) }
```

Don't know why I had to put a comma after `(`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear-Host

$s = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18

$count = $s.Length

$split = $count/2

$split --

$b = $s[0..$split]

$split ++

$a = $s[$split..$count]

write-host "first array"

$b

write-host "next array"

$a

#clean up
Get-Variable -Exclude PWD,*Preference | Remove-Variable -EA 0
```

Comment: Could you please add more details to this answer? It's just code only, so a bit of explaination would be great

Answer (score 1):

A simple method using a [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-7.0) to collect input objects elements and output without enumerating using [`$PSCmdlet.WriteObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdlet.writeobject?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0#system-management-automation-cmdlet-writeobject(system-object)). This is compatible with Windows PowerShell 5.1.

```bash
function Split-Collection {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [object[]] $InputObject,

        [Parameter(Position = 0)]
        [ValidateRange(1, [int]::MaxValue)]
        [int] $ChunkSize = 5
    )

    begin {
        $list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
    }
    process {
        foreach($item in $InputObject) {
            $list.Add($item)
            if($list.Count -eq $ChunkSize) {
                $PSCmdlet.WriteObject($list.ToArray())
                $list.Clear()
            }
        }
    }
    end {
        if($list.Count) {
            $PSCmdlet.WriteObject($list.ToArray())
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
PS ..\pwsh> 0..10 | Split-Collection 3 | ForEach-Object { "[$_]" }

[0 1 2]
[3 4 5]
[6 7 8]
[9 10]


PS ..\pwsh> Split-Collection -InputObject (0..10) 3 | ForEach-Object { "[$_]" }

[0 1 2]
[3 4 5]
[6 7 8]
[9 10]
```

An even simpler way to do it if using PowerShell 7+ is with [`Enumerable.Chunk`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.chunk?view=net-7.0) from LINQ.

```bash
PS ..\pwsh> [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Chunk([int[]] (0..10), 3) | ForEach-Object { "[$_]" }

[0 1 2]
[3 4 5]
[6 7 8]
[9 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

If collection is big enough (e.g. millions of elements), then performance may matter. None of the solutions proposed before satisfied me first of all from performance standpoints. Here is my solution:

```
Function Chunk {
    param(
        [object[]] $source,
        [int] $size = 1)
    $chunkCount = [Math]::Ceiling($source.Count / $size)
    0 .. ($chunkCount - 1) `
    | ForEach-Object {
        $startIndex = $_ * $size
        $endIndex = [Math]::Min(($_ + 1) * $size, $source.Count)
        ,$source[$startIndex .. ($endIndex - 1)]
    }
}
```

Example of usage:

```
Chunk @(1..17) 4 | foreach { $_ -join ',' }
```

Output:

```
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
9,10,11,12
13,14,15,16
17
```

Performance measure:

```
(Measure-Command { Chunk @(1..1000000) 1000 }).TotalMilliseconds
```

Output: `140.467` (in milliseconds)