# How to full purge the Azure CDN through PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, azure-cdn

The cmdlet [Unpublish-AzureRmCdnEndpointContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.cdn/unpublish-azurermcdnendpointcontent?view=azurermps-6.1.0) has a `-PurgeContent` option, however the naive usage:

```
Unpublish-AzureRmCdnEndpointContent 
  -EndpointName $endpointName 
  -ProfileName $profileName 
  -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName 
  -PurgeContent "/*"
```

Only appears to purge the files at the root (aka no `/` in the path), and not the *nested* files. How can I ensure that everything gets purged from all nested levels at once?

Answer (score 1):

> Only appears to purge the files at the root (aka no / in the path), and not the nested files. How can I ensure that everything gets purged from all nested levels at once?

According to [Purge an Azure CDN endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-purge-endpoint), we could use `"/*"` to purge all folders, sub-folders and files under an endpoint with `/*` in the path.

> Wildcard purge: Asterisk `(*)` may be used as a wildcard. Purge all folders, sub-folders and files under an endpoint with /* in the path.

We also could capture the network from the azure portal when we try to purge all from the endpoint.

[image]

We also could use the fiddler to capture the API rest during run the command.

It is the same with that we operate checking [purge all] from azure portal.

[image]

I test it with following code.

```
$endpointName = "endpoint name"
$resourceGroupName = "resource group"
$profileName = "profileName"
[string[]]$purge = @("/*")  
Unpublish-AzureRmCdnEndpointContent -EndpointName $endpointName -ProfileName $profileName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -PurgeContent $purge -Debug
```

Note: it takes long time to finish this task.

[image]

Comment: I tried this solution and while the command "succeeded" none of the files were actually purged. I'll put in the answer for what I did shortly.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried the other answer and the command returns without error but the files weren't actually purged. I ended up writing a script that enumerated the source files on disk and purged them. You can only specify 50 at once though so I had to adapt this answer:

[Powershell break a long array into a array of array with length of N in one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13888253/powershell-break-a-long-array-into-a-array-of-array-with-length-of-n-in-one-line)

This is a little specific to what I needed since the step before is to use azcopy to put the files in storage in the first place...

```
$currentDirectory = get-location | select -ExpandProperty Path
$files = ls ".\" -Recurse | select -ExpandProperty FullName | %{ 
    $_.Replace($currentDirectory ,"\") } | %{ $_.Replace("\", "/") }

$counter = [pscustomobject] @{ Value = 0 }
$groups = $files | Group-Object -Property { [math]::Floor($counter.Value++ / 50) }

Import-Module azurerm

$profileName = "yourprofile"
$endpoint = "yourendpoint"
$profile = Get-AzureRmCdnProfile -ProfileName $profileName

$groups | %{
    Unpublish-AzureRmCdnEndpointContent `
        -EndpointName $endpoint `
        -ProfileName $profileName `
        -ResourceGroupName $profile.resourceGroupName `
        -PurgeContent $_.Group
}
```

Depending on how many files you have you may want to use Start-Job to thread it. I haven't needed to yet as it's about 5-10 seconds per call.

Hope this helps someone.