# O365 Powershell | Breaking up a long list into two sets of 100

Tags: powershell, office365

I am looking to create a rule in Office 365 applied to all of the members in our org.

I would like this rule to append a warning on all incoming email from outside the organization with the same Display Names as our users.

When I attempt to apply it to all of the users in our org I get an error stating that the rule is too long.

In order to solve that I pulled a group, but I am still about 1000 characters over the limit.

**I would like to make two variables, that each hold one half of the list, created by this command:**

```
(Get-DistibutionGroupMember -Identity email@contoso.com -ResultSize Unlimited).DisplayName
```

I have attempted to modify the ResultSize parameter, but what I would need is result 1-100 and then 100-200 from the same list.

Another caveat to this problem is that the list cannot be static. It is something that the script will have to update every time it is run.

There is a sub-string command that you can use on a particular username that I have utilized when I made something for AD, but I am not aware of any way to break up a list like this.

If anyone has any other ways to solve this issue I would be more than open to any suggestion.

Thanks for taking the time to read this!

Comment: Okay so I think I have figured it out: 

I can do $DisplayNames.Substring(0)[100..200]. 
From what I understand this pulls all values between 100 and 200.

This is what I needed. Sorry for the question! Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: You could also pipe the variable into `select-object -first 100` and  `select-object -last 99` just be careful this way with math. Or you may over lap some or mis select some

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing it.  I found it very readable.

My favorite one is this one:

```
$ObjectList = 1..1000 
$Step = 100 
$counter = [pscustomobject] @{ Value = 0 } 
$ObjectListSplitted = $ObjectList | Group-Object -Property { math]::Floor($counter.Value++ / $step) }
```

Then if you want to show the *third* subset just use this format :

```
$ObjectListSplitted[3].Group
```

Have a look to [this solution already explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13888253/powershell-break-a-long-array-into-a-array-of-array-with-length-of-n-in-one-line).

As a note other languages are capable of slicing an array of object with a start, stop and a step, have a look [here](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html) if you're curious.